# Failing to write post request in MEAN stack app

Tags: node.js, post, mean-stack

I am trying to adapt a tutorial to another project to get the hang of the mean stack and run into trouble for a post request.

I'am trying to add a new element to the reviews array :

```
var CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
code: String,
name: String,
reviews: [{ 
    body: String
}]
```

On the front I have the following function to call the courses service addReview function :

```
courses.addReview($scope.course._id, tempReview).success(function (review){
            //$scope.course.reviews.push(review);
            console.log('addingReview');
        });
```

The courses service addReview function is :

```
    o.addReview = function (id, review) {
    console.log('posting Review')
    return $http.post('/courses/'+ id + '/reviews', review );
};
```

All of this should be alright since my post request is succesfully sent to the server (I get a 200 message on the console for the post).

Here is the code from my backend :

```
var Course = mongoose.model('Course');
    router.post('/courses/:course/reviews', function ( req, res, next){

    Course.findById(req.course, function (err, course){
        course.addReview(req.body);
        res.json(course);
        res.end();
    })
});
```

and the addReview function from my course model :

```
CourseSchema.methods.addReview = function (review) {
    this.reviews.push(review);
    this.save(review);
};
```

I have read several blog post but still don't understand how to write that post request for an array... Any help would be much appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: 'how to write that post request for an array' is a little confusing. Apparently you don't 'add new element to the reviews array ', you adding new document to MongoDB collection 'courses'. Could you check if there is any changes this collection?

Comment: There is no change in the collection. What makes you think I am adding an element to course instead of the field reviews?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. Backend code looks fine... I Would do couple things: if(err){console.log(err)} - to check if there is any info; console.log(course) to see if we actually finding anything in collection (all that in `Course.findById` block)

Comment: hey, I followed your suggestion and used a console.log to print course and it does print the course I am targetting and it shows that the review I added was added to the course. BUT, when I curl immediately afterward to see the content of the course and check if the review was added, it doesn't show. My hunch would be that I add the review to the course, but doesn't save modification in DB. Is that possible ?

Comment: That's it ! I added a little save and it works :)

Comment: Cool! Post your code as answer. It might be useful for others.

Comment: Thanks again for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, I was making the modification but not saving it in db, here is the code I now use :

```
router.post('/courses/:course/reviews', function ( req, res, next){

    Course.findById(req.course, function (err, course){
        course.addReview(req.body);
        course.save(function (err, course){
            if(err){ return next(err);}
            console.log(course);
            res.json(course);
            res.end();
        });

    })

});
```